Format date and time column in datatable should not show the same value in all rows
I am using Flutter datatable class.
I need to show a different date and time value in each row.
The issue is that all rows show the same value.
Preferably, I need to show the date created date and time, but Flutter has only date modified.
Could you please provide your feedback.
Thank You
Here is my code:
DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat();
  List<DataRow> myDataRow = [];
  DateTime FileLastModified=DateTime.timestamp();
  
  Future<List<DataRow>> myTest() async {
    Directory dir = Directory('C:/test');
    final List<FileSystemEntity> entities = await dir.list().toList();
    for(var file in entities) {
      if(file.path.isNotEmpty){
        File(file.path).lastModified().then((value){
          FileLastModified = value;
        });
        myDataRow.add(DataRow(cells: <DataCell>[
          DataCell(Text(dateFormat.format(FileLastModified).toString())),
        ]));
      }
    }
    return myDataRow;
  }

Issue: I see the same value in all rows.

The actual files dates are these:


Can you provide ui code and try to debug by log entities variable to make sure that every data you got is correct

It seems you only take data for 1 index. In DataTable you provide data in rows, you can use:
rows: yourList.map(
        (e) => DataRow(use 'e' here),
      ).toList(),

or
rows: <DataRow>[
  for (var item in yourList)
    DataRow(use 'item' here),         
]

